# How can I see the line which triggers a runtime error in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: runtime-error, mysql-workbench

The **SQL Workbench** indicates **syntax errors** by replacing the line number with the *red x symbol*. When a **runtime error** occurs, the only information I get is its *Time*, *Action* and *Message* via the *Action Output* and not the line which it occurred. How can I see the line that triggered the **runtime error** ?

Answer (score 0):

The message (Response) contains the line number. Hover your mouse over the response to see the entire response, or right-click on it and choose "Copy Response" and then paste/view it somewhere else.

Comment: I copied the response and there is no line number inside. Here is an example: `Error Code: 1364. Field 'ssn' doesn't have a default value`.
Hovering my mouse over the error displays **Action**, **Response** and**Duration** but no line number. In case it matters, I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Are you sure the SQL Editor shows an 'x' for this code? That's not a syntax error, so I suspect it does not.

Comment: Ah, so those mean the query failed whereas the [x] in the SQL editor means there is a syntax error. Your SQL lacks an SQL syntax error so this makes it tricky. Bottom line: Workbench does not display this information.

Comment: So there is no possible way to display the line where the error occurred ?